# Find eigenvalues of a matrix using Perron–Frobenius theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to find the largest eigenvalue of a matrix containing only positive entries:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
e^{a} & 1 & e^{-a} \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
e^{-a} & 1 & e^{a} \end{array} 
\right)
$$

now, instead of writing the 3rd order characteristic polinomila to find eigenvalues, I see that there is an eigenvector

$$\vec{v_1}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
0 \\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array} 
\right)
$$

and it is easy to check that the corresponding eigenvalue is

$\lambda_1=2\sinh(a)$

and because of the Perron–Frobenius theorem I can say that this is not the largest eigenvalue because the corresponding eigenvector contains not only positive entries.
Now, I know that the knowledge of that eigenvector and eigenvalue makes possible to reduce the characteristic polinomial to a second order one:

$$p_t(\lambda)=(2\sinh(a)-\lambda)\cdot p(\lambda^2)$$

then, writing the third order polinomial and factor as I stated above is quite a long procedure. What is the fastest way to write the second order characteristic polinomial $p(\lambda^2)$? I.e. I am asking if there is a way faster than the one I stated above to remove the eigenspace relative to the eigenvector I found from the eigenvalue problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since the matrix is hermitian, its eigenvectors are orthogonal.  Consider a second eigenvector in a form such that $\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_2}=0.\,$

For example
$$\vec{v_2}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
x \\
1 \end{array} 
\right)
$$
and solve for the unknown $x$.
$$M\cdot\vec{v_2}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x+2\cosh(a)\\
x+2 \\
x+2\cosh(a) \end{array} 
\right)=\lambda\vec{v_2}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\lambda\\
\lambda x \\
\lambda \end{array} 
\right)
$$
Now equate the vector components.  The first component yields an expression for $\lambda$, which we can substitute into the second component to get
$$ x+2 = \big(x+2c\big)x$$where $c=\cosh(a)$.

This is simply a quadratic equation 
$$ x^2 + (2c-1)x - 2 = 0$$
Picking the positive root for x yields
$$
x = \frac{(1-2c) + \sqrt{(1-2c)(1-2c)+8}}{2}
$$
Now $\vec{v_2}$ has all positive elements, and the associated eigenvalue is  $$\eqalign{\lambda &= x+2c\cr &= \frac{(1+2c) + \sqrt{(1-2c)(1-2c)+8}}{2}}$$